# decrypting files on another server

Tags: ubuntu, openssl

I am encrypting a tar file (created using `tar cfz`) on an Ubuntu 10.04 box using the following command:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -in myfile.tar -out myfile.enc.tar -pass pass:${P}
```

Now I copy the encrypted file to another machine and decrypt it using following command:

```
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -in myfile.enc.tar -out myfile.tar -pass pass:${P}
```

But I'm not able to open the decrypted arhchive file `myfile.tar`. Am I doing something wrong here or this is not possible?

<strike>**EDIT:** *Working now I think I missed a parameter during decryption (`-salt`)*</strike>

```
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -salt
```

Comment: Sure I will but have to wait some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the culprit seems to be a missing parameter `-salt` that I used while encrypting. The following made it work:

```
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -salt -in myfile.enc.tar -out myfile.tar -pass pass:${P}
```